# ESXI 4.1 USB key not passing through

Tags: vmware-esxi

I just did a conversion from an Acronis echo backup of a windows XP machine, and I am having trouble getting the USB device to pass through (in this case a USB license dongle). I added the USB controller, but the USB devices will not show up in the list.

I can see the dongle from a fresh install of Server 2008, but not this machine.

One note, when opening up the settings I get this error:

*"An IDE controller is found but the virtual machine does not support this option."*

After clicking the "OK" button, I get this:

*"A flat backing option was not found"*

Any ideas?

Comment: Not every device works with passthrough, that's why why have a HCL, for instance I have some USB disks that work and others that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to end up reloading my Acronis Echo image. Using the converter messes it up somehow. Using the Acronis boot disk to restore does the job though.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but an easy workaround: USB license dongles, especially the ones from Aladin, have been found to work quite well with USB network hubs [like this Belkin model](http://www.belkin.com/networkusbhub/). This way, you would not need any virtualization support for the device but could simply access it over a network connection.

Comment: Cool! I didn't realize that would work, unfortionitly we don jave the budget for one. Will keep that in mind for the future though.